# How to migrate schema & template from Tridion 2011 to WEB 8

Tags: web8, upgrade

We want to migrate Tridion 2011 SP1 to WEB 8, with exist content together. Since WEB 8 require different OS and DB version. So the main steps we prepare to do is like below:

1. Install WEB 8 Servers & DBs;
2. Backup 2011 DB and restore it at new DB environment;
3. Run SDL WEB8 powershell script to migrate the DB structure;
4. Install SDL WEB 8 content Manager and all other service/roles;

But we notice there are a lot of physical files for schema and template, like Carousel.xsd for schema and CT Carousel.dwt for template. Is it ok we just copy them to the new WEB 8 server or we need to run some other tool to migrate them?

Thanks,

Qiang

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Schemas (.xsd) and template building blocks (e.g. .dwt) are also stored in the Tridion CM database.

I am not sure where you are seeing those files on your file system? If you are looking at those files via WebDav, then you are actually looking at files in the CM database, and not on your file system.

Therefore your upgrade approach looks good and your schemas and templates will be available in the Web 8 system, as long as you meant "Upgrade" and not "Migrate" in your point 3.

Comment: I do check them by WebDav, now it make sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There are no physical files for schema definitions, not sure where or why you're getting this information.

All data definitions are stored in the database, upgrading it using the scripts will provide you the same schemas and templates that you had before. The only things that may need file system copying and re-registering are extensions - UI or event system, workflow, etc. Templates, schemas, content don't need anything else than the database upgrade.

Comment: ah Nuno is too fast for me :)